# could not find driver (php, PDO)

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I find the error: could not find driver in the next script. I'm breaking my head over it now for some time now maybe you see the my fault.

This is my code:

```
class ConnectStation {
  private $host = "localhost";
  private $DatabaseType = "mysql";
  private $database = array (
    1 => "Database_one",
    2 => "Database_two",
    3 => "Database_true"
);
private $user1 = "MyUsername1";
private $pass1 = "MyPassword1";
private $user2 = "MyUsername2";
private $pass2 = "MyPassword2";

public function ConnectDB($user, $database){
if ($database==""){$database=1;}
try{
    switch ($user){
       case "ReadOnly":
       $connection = new PDO("'".$this->DatabaseType.":host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->database[$database]."', '".$this->user1."', '".$this->pass1."'");
       $connection->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
       return $connection;
       break;
       case "Admin":
       $connection = new PDO("'".$this->DatabaseType.":host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->database[$database]."', '".$this->user2."', '".$this->pass2."'");
       $connection->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
       return $connection;
       break;
       }
    }
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
}
```

Oke so far the connection than the scrip i use for a query to send to the database. the code is like this:

```
$userCard = new ConnectStation;

$query = "SELECT username FROM users";
foreach ($this->ConnectDB('ReadOnly', 1)->query($query) as $row){
echo $row['username']."<br>";
}
```

Any help ore advise is welcome?

Comment: Are you sure that it is POD and not PDO?

Comment: Is there a driver called `'mysql`? **Note the leading quotation mark.**

Comment: As Aswin said...its PDO not POD

Comment: Sorry typo It shoot be PDO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to the PDO constructor is totally screwed up with unnecessary quotes and weird argument order. Just do:

```
$dsn = sprintf('%s:host=%s;dbname=%s', $this->DatabaseType, $this->host, $this->database[$database]);
$connection = new PDO($dsn, $this->user1, $this->pass1);
```